# How do I release C style arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nscopying

I have a `QuantumClone` class which has an array of `CGPoint`s. The single `QuantumPilot` object creates a `QuantumClone` at the beginning of each level. During the next level the `QuantumPilot` records its velocities to its `QuantumClone`. At the beginning of a new level the game loop runs this code

```
QuantumClone *c = [[self.pilot clone] copy];
c.bulletDelegate = self;
c.weapon = self.pilot.weapon;
[self.clones addObject:c];
```

But eventually the game will be reset and each `QuantumClone` object in the clones `NSMutableArray` will be removed.

Am I leaking memory by assigning values to the `CGPoint pastVelocities[4551]` ?

How do I reset these? I can't release them since they are not Objective-C objects. Do I need to call C functions to release this memory?

```
@interface QuantumClone : QuantumPilot <NSCopying> {
  CGPoint pastVelocities[4551];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    QuantumClone *c = [[[QuantumClone alloc] init] autorelease];
    c.weapon = self.weapon;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4551; i++) {
        [c recordVelocity:pastVelocities[i] firing:pastFireTimings[i]];
    }
    [c recordLatestIndex:timeIndex];
    return c;
}

- (void)recordVelocity:(CGPoint)vel firing:(BOOL)firing {
    CGPoint p = pastVelocities[timeIndex];
    p.x = vel.x;
    p.y = vel.y;
    pastVelocities[timeIndex] = p;
    bool fired = firing;
    pastFireTimings[timeIndex] = fired;
    timeIndex++;
}

@interface QuantumPilot : CCNode {}
....
@property (nonatomic, retain) QuantumClone *clone;

- (void)copyDeltas {
    [self.clone recordVelocity:ccp(self.vel.x, -self.vel.y) firing:self.firing];
}

- (void)createClone {
    self.clone = [[[QuantumClone alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.clone.active = YES;
    self.clone.weapon = self.weapon;
}
```

Comment: Comment as to the downvote? I'm trying to ensure I'm not leaking memory by assigning to these CGPoints

Comment: struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint; in CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h

Comment: Precisely!  And what is an array of structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I leaking memory by assigning values to the CGPoint `pastVelocities[4551]` ?

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**: The array in your code is a big chunk of contiguous memory where all `CGRect`s live in, and it has automatic storage, which means it will be allocated and deallocated automatically (when it goes out of scope). In other words, when its parent object is destroyed, the array will be gone along with those 4551 objects.

You can verify its size by printing the result of `sizeof(pastVelocities)`. Dividing the result by `sizeof(CGRect)` will tell you how many objects of this type can be stored in it.

A deallocation must be married to an explicit allocation. You only need to release memory that is allocated dynamically (explicitly), for example, using the `alloc` function family (malloc, calloc, realloc, etc).

> How do I reset these?

```
memset(pastVelocities, 0, sizeof(pastVelocities));
```

This will reset the entire array.

Comment: Ok, thought so! Wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

jweyrich beat me to it, but I'll go ahead and post this in case it helps ;)

––

You aren't leaking.  The runtime allocates enough memory to hold all ivars.  In this case, each QuantumClone instance will use ~18k (~36k on 64-bit) more memory than a QuantumPilot, since you have told the runtime that it needs to allocate enough ivar storage for 4551 CGPoints.

If pastVelocities were a `CGFloat *` rather than a `CGFloat[4551]`, you would need to manually allocate the memory via `malloc` and then call `free` in `-dealloc`.  However, by declaring it as a fixed size C-array, the runtime handles it (but at the expense of making every QuantumClone a rather huge object).

That said, this whole approach seems fragile.  Why 4551?  Why C arrays?  There is nothing wrong with using C arrays for performance, but I strongly suspect this is premature optimization.

Comment: Good point on `this whole approach seems fragile. Why 4551? Why C arrays?`. +1 :-)

Comment: 4551 is a specific number based on the maximum number of frames the game can run. I can't put a variable instead of 4551, so I just use the magic number.

Comment: A `CGFloat *` ivar would allow you to `malloc` a variable size, and `realloc` when you need it to grow.  If you need to make this less-fragile in the future, you might want to go that direction.  Or just use an `NSArray` of NSValue-wrapped CGPoints.  There is nothing wrong with pure-C arrays of values, but usually any performance benefit from using them is negated if you have to call an Obj-C method per insert.